# How to tell mut send all files but not todays file?

Tags: mutt

How to tell mut, attach all *.csv files but not today's active csv file where are still logging app running on backround..

**Actuall Script:**

```
mutt -s "$(date -d 'now' +%Y_week%V)" -a /var/log/app/*.csv -- example@example.com
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the filenames sort properly (i.e. they are all in the format `yyyy-mm-dd.csv`) then you could do something like:

`mutt -s "$(date -d 'now' +%Y_week%V)" -a $(find /var/log/app/ -maxdepth 1 -name \*\.csv | sort -r | sed '1d') -- example@example.com`

This will sort the filenames with the most recent on top and the `sed` call will discard the top one. This will only work if you're sure today's file already exists. If that isn't the case, you will omit yesterday's.

If you need this to work even if today's file isn't yet there, you could do:

`mutt -s "$(date -d 'now' +%Y_week%V)" -a $(find /var/log/app/ -maxdepth 1 -name \*\.csv | grep -v "$(date +%Y-%m-%d.csv)") -- example@example.com`

You will of course need to change the `$(date +%Y-%m-%d.csv)` call to generate the filename you are trying to exclude, if it is in a different format.